# Getting string instead of defining it in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, string, sdk

I'm trying to get a string from strings.xml into my Java file:

This is my Java code:

```
public class LGDial extends ActionBarActivity{
public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
        "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };
```

Can someone please tell me how to define the text in strings.xml then get it.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You should have searched here first http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Strings in xml, you need to set like this first in your strings.xml of res/values.

```
<string name="app_name">Your App</string>
```

then you can use the string you want like below.

```
getString(R.string.app_name);
```

I hope it will help for you.